# Simplifying an expression

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can the following expression be simplified ?.

Let $\,\, n,r_{i} \in \mathbb{N}\,\,$ and $\,\, 0\ <\ p,z\ <\ 1$.

$$
\prod_{i = 0}^{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}z^{k}{k + r_{i} - 1 \choose r_{i} - 1}
\, p^{r_{i}}\,\left(\, 1 - p\, \right)^{k}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\prod_{i = 0}^{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}z^{k}
{k + r_{i} - 1 \choose r_{i} - 1}\, p^{r_{i}}\,\pars{1 - p}^{k}} =
\prod_{i = 0}^{n} p^{r_{i}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{k + r_{i} - 1 \choose k}\bracks{z\pars{1 - p}}^{\, k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\prod_{i = 0}^{n}p^{r_{i}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{-r_{i} \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\bracks{z\pars{1 - p}}^{\, k} =
\prod_{i = 0}^{n}p^{r_{i}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{-r_{i} \choose k}\bracks{-z\pars{1 - p}}^{\, k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\prod_{i = 0}^{n}p^{r_{i}}\,\,\bracks{1 -z\pars{1 - p}}^{\,-r_{i}} =
\prod_{i = 0}^{n}\bracks{p \over 1 -z\pars{1 - p}}^{\, r_{i}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\color{#f00}{\bracks{p \over 1 -z\pars{1 - p}}^{\mu}\,,\qquad
\mu \equiv \sum_{i = 0}^{n}r_{i}}.\qquad\qquad\verts{z\pars{1 - p}} < 1.
\end{align}